# In Python how to recover from joke statements like True = False

Tags: python, python-2.7

I started learning Python just today using Python 2.7 and I have a question here about global variables True and False:

It seems I can overwrite the value of True and False as this:

```
False = True
# now the value of variable False is also true.
True = False
# because the value of False is true, after this the value of True is still true.

if True(or False):
    print 'xxxx'
else:
    print 'yyyy'
```

Now wether we put True or we put False as the if condition, it always prints 'xxxx'.

Then how to recover from that fault situation? I imagine that we could use something like:

```
True = 1==1
False = 1!=1
```

but that seems bit dodgy to me. Is there any better way to do that?

Thanks.

(Also, it seems in Python 3.3 this action is no longer allowed?)

Comment: just delete them.... `del True, False`

Comment: Thanks all! del True/False and `__buildin__`.True are both neat answers, also good to know they are keywords in 3.3!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to "recover" from this is to not let it happen.

That said, you can always use the `bool()` type to access `True` and `False` again. (`bool()` always returns one of the two boolean singletons.)

Example:

```
>>> bool
<type 'bool'>
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool(1) is bool('true')
True
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
>>> True is False
True
>>> False is bool()
True
>>> True = bool(1)
>>> True is bool(1)
True
>>> True is False
False
>>> True is bool()
False
>>> bool()
False
>>> True is bool(2)
True
>>> True is bool('true')
True
>>>
```

If this is a simple `True = 'something'` binding, then what happens is that a new name `True` is created in the current namespace--the `__builtins__` module is not altered.  In this case you can simply delete (unbind) the "True" name in your namespace. Then Python will use the one defined in `__builtins__` again.

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> True is __builtins__.True
True
>>> True = 'redefined'
>>> __builtins__.True is True
False
>>> del True
>>> __builtins__.True is True
True
```

None of this is possible in Python 3 because `True` and `False` are no longer names (variables) but keywords.

Comment: If someone has mischievously swapped True and False, then he might have replaced `bool` too, no? `True = 1==1` doesn't suffer from that problem.

Comment: @DSM but if one was going that far - I'd either have replaced the executable or have my own `sys.settrace` somewhere ;)

Comment: You could probably make a global metaclass where False is True and True is False? (i.e. alter the `bool` type to return the opposite of what it normally does.)

Comment: It's not quite that simple. Check out `>>> True, False = False, True; bool(1) is True` for some fun. :-)

Answer (score 4):

They're not "global" variables as such - they're built-ins.... They're available in `__builtin__` (no **s**) - and you can do what you will "for a joke". Note that doing this kind of thing is mostly for mocking/profilers and things of that kin...

And no, you can't do that in the 3.x series, because `True` and `False` are keywords, not (sort of) singletons like in 2.x

Comment: +1 for mentioning they are keywords in Python 3.x. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

If things aren't *too* bad, you could set `True = __builtins__.True`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `__builtin__.True`?

Comment: @SamMussmann I've put `__builtin__` in my answer - though it's not uncommon to see `__builtins__` but that's just a CPython quirk as it were